# Enter UEFI-Shell using the UEFI-bootmanager?

Tags: uefi

How do I create a UEFI-Bootmanager entry that jumps into the built in EFI-Shell using efibootmgr? If this is not possible: Is there another way? Does every UEFI come with a shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UEFI Shell is a regular .efi program, which you can [download](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Obtaining_UEFI_Shell).

Store it at `\SHELLX64.EFI` or a similar path on the EFI filesystem, and add it to the UEFI boot manager the usual way.

Comment: Some EFIs come with a built-in shell that can be accessed via the firmware's own options. As a general rule, though, grawity's advice is the way to go. Beware, though: Some shells are incompatible with some EFIs, so you may need to try two or three before finding one that works. An incompatible shell binary generally hangs when launched.